# Issue in rendering .js file in springboot application

Tags: javascript, html, spring-boot

[image]
[image]
I am creating a springboot application. In templates folder I am keeping html files and in static folder I am keeping javascript files. But html files are not able to render javascript files. I am getting following error "app.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()". Please help me with correct files structure of both the files in springboot application also if I need to add anything in pom.xml or in application.properties file then please tell me.

I have created a registration form and put it inside the templates folder of springboot application. I have one app.js file inside the static folder of spring boot application which is helping in using an api to render the country, state and city as a dropdown list. When I am writing that script code directly inside the html file then it is working fine but when I am trying to import app.js file then it is not working.

Comment: Please post your code as a [mre]. We cannot conceivably help without seeing what you are actually doing.

Comment: Question is not related to any code. I just want to know how to render javascript files in springboot application. 
here is a snippet of including app.js file in a registration html file: <script src = "/static/app.js"></script>. 
While running application when opening registration form so it is failing to render app.js file. Error I am getting on the console is : Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://localhost:8080/api/registration/static/app.js”. owner:96:30

Comment: I have added the screenshots. May be this will help to understand the issue.